# Is the mouse wheel behaviour of Mac OS X or Linux possible in Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, mac, mouse-wheel

In Linux or Mac OS X, every window I hover over registers mouse wheel events without being the focused window. For instance I can have two windows open at the same time and scroll in each one of them without clicking either of them first.

Can this behaviour somehow be translated to Windows? Is there a tool or a hidden preference that I can set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [WizMouse](http://lifehacker.com/5146250/wizmouse-adds-scrolling-to-out-of-focus-windows):

```
"Makes your mouse wheel behave the way it always should have."
Works on 32 and 64 bit versions of Windows 2000, XP, Vista and Windows 7

* Scrolls windows under the mouse without having to click first
* Enables the mouse wheel in applications that don't support mouse wheels
```

Comment: @Amenti Please avoid “thanks” comments. Thank answerers by accepting or upvoting the answers.

Answer (score 0):

[AlwaysMouseWheel](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/AlwaysMouseWheel) is another option, which I have found works better with Windows 8 Modern UI than WizMouse.

Also, similar question: 
[On Windows 7, is there any way to make the scrollwheel's focus follow the mouse?](https://superuser.com/questions/368688/on-windows-is-there-any-way-to-make-the-scrollwheels-focus-follow-the-mouse)