# Controlling browser while another window is being used

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, opera

Is there a way to scroll the browser while having another window open.  For instance I would like to be able to scroll down the browser while I have a terminal window open which is opaque.  So that I can see example code while not having to jump back and forth.

Is this possible to do on any browsers?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: linux Ubuntu or Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Well, for Windows 7, you could use a utility like [Deskpins](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/deskpins.html) to keep your terminal window always on top.  As has been answered in this question [Make window always on top?](https://superuser.com/questions/28907/make-window-always-on-top)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a keystroke broadcasting software like [Keyclone](http://solidice.com/keyclone).

That way you can use arrow keys to navigate up/downwards in both Windows. You can choose to which window/application the keystrokes get forwarded to. I believe you can also configure WHICH keys get forwarded (so that when you type code you don't forward those keystrokes, just the navigational keys)

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, this is the default behaviour anyway - the scroll wheel controls whatever the mouse is currently over, whether or not that's the window that has focus. Unless something's changed in Ubuntu 12.04 or you've changed the default behaviour?

As for Windows, try using [AlwaysScrollWheel](http://download.cnet.com/AlwaysMouseWheel/3000-2072_4-75452183.html), as I pointed out [here](https://superuser.com/a/419881/109305). Not sure if that makes your question a possible duplicate...