# Open inactive window by scrolling up on taskbar icon

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, taskbar

*Question:*

I want to use my scroll wheel to open an inactive window when I scroll up on an icon in the **taskbar** in Windows 10. The same behavior as in Ubuntu when you scroll up on an icon in the taskbar.

Is there a setting to do this, or program?

*Why:*

I've been working on a Linux system and am now used to scroll up on a icon in order to open an inactive window. This is has nice feeling for the work flow, I would like to transfer this to Windows 10, but can't find anything that does this. Yes, I know I can just click on it, but sometimes it's nice to just scroll as my finger is already there a lot of the time when working.

**Note**: I'm **not** looking for the inactive hover over scroll functionality, that works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to do this. Basically you tell it that if your cursor is over the taskbar or one of the preview thumbnails that opens from it, then scrolling up with your mouse wheel sends a left click, otherwise it scrolls up.

This requires using the Windows API. I've tested this script and it seems to work like you want, though I believe it will send a click **anywhere** on the taskbar, and not just over window icons. I'm afraid that's the best I could manage.

```
GetWinUnderMouse(what="Title")
{
    ; Allocate the memory (8 bytes) for the POINT structure
    VarSetCapacity(POINT, 8, 0)

    ; Call the GetCursorPos function with the address 
    ; of the POINT structure we just created
    DllCall("GetCursorPos", uint, &POINT)

    ; Use NumGet to get the information out of the structure
    ; the x-value is stored in the first 4 bytes, and 
    ; the y-value in the last 4
    X := NumGet(POINT, 0)
    Y := NumGet(POINT, 4)

    return GetWinAtCoords(X, Y, what)
}

GetWinAtCoords(x,y,what="Title")      ; by SKAN and Learning one
{
    ; Returns Title/ID/Class/PID of window at given coordinates
    WinID := DllCall( "GetAncestor", UInt      ; by SKAN
           ,DllCall( "WindowFromPoint", Int,X, Int,Y )
           , UInt, GA_ROOT := 2)
    if what = Title
    {
        WinGetTitle, WinTitle, ahk_id %WinID%
        Return WinTitle
    }
    else if what = ID
    Return WinID
    else if what = Class
    {
        WinGetClass, WinClass, ahk_id %WinID%
        Return WinClass
    }
    else if what = PID
    {
        WinGet, WinPID, PID, ahk_id %WinID%
        Return WinPID
    }
}

WheelUp::
    PointedClass := GetWinUnderMouse("Class")
    if (PointedClass = "TaskListThumbnailWnd" or PointedClass = "Shell_TrayWnd")
    {
        Send, {LButton}
    }
    else
    {
        Send, {WheelUp}
    }
Return
```

If you add a tilde (~) before `WheelUp::` then the wheel up functionality will remain even when a left click is sent (you can also do away with the `else` clause in there if you do so).

To use, simply install the program, put the script in a file and run it.

Comment: *Ohhhh*, thank you so much! You could've just suggested the Autohotkey and make me do the work, I almost feel bad. You might want to try it yourself aswell, once you're used to it, no turning around.

Comment: I have some experience with AutoHotkey and thought it'd be simpler, but it actually did take a bit of work to get it working. XD
No matter; I'm glad it works, and it was fun to make. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You could use some programs such as AlwaysMouseWheel, X-Button Mouse Control!
[On Windows 7, is there any way to make the scrollwheel's focus follow the mouse?](https://superuser.com/questions/368688/on-windows-7-is-there-any-way-to-make-the-scrollwheels-focus-follow-the-mouse)

Comment: Somehow, I can't seem to find the option I want/need. I can bind left click to scrolling up, yet that will just totally disable scrolling up. I want it to essentially do both. Ideally I would even only want it to left click when on an inactive window icon.

Comment: have you enable Activate windows when scrolling option in x-button mouse setting? then in layer wheel up option, you could choose left click

Comment: Yes, but then it doesnt scroll anymore, it just ledt clikcs

Comment: It's strange. After set it, I could scroll up the wheel to open the taskbar icon such as Edge and so on.